# É possível recuperar uma conta excluída e mesclar com a atual?

Tags: suporte

Na minha conta antiga, eu tinha clicado em excluir kkkk, mas cancelei, porém depois de 1 dia mais ou menos a conta foi excluída mesmo assim.

Já faz um tempinho que aconteceu, cerca de uns 15 dias, recebi a dica de um usuário que poderia abrir uma pergunta aqui pedindo a restauração da conta antiga e também gostaria que mesclasse com esta nova aqui, por favor :D (Tem o mesmo e-mail).

Ex-pefil da minha conta antiga: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45722/vinicius-lima

Comment: O jnat vai dar uma solução parcial.

Comment: Troca a aceitação.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**É possível reassociar as publicações do perfil anterior com este novo, sim.**

No entanto, há umas quantas coisas que aproveito para deixar claras aqui. **O processo de remoção de conta é, geralmente, automatizado e bastante inócuo** — grande parte dos utilizadores que removem a sua conta não teve grandes contribuições para o site, nem participou muito na comunidade, portanto não é sequer necessária intervenção humana da nossa (SE/SO) parte.

[Há algumas excepções](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/208518), no entanto: **se um utilizador tiver votado bastante, e/ou de maneira a que afecte muitos *outros* utilizadores, aí a remoção tem que ser aprovada por um humano**. Dependendo de alguns factores citados na ligação acima, esses votos podem ser mantidos, ou ***irrevogavelmente* removidos** — no teu caso foram removidos. Os votos feitos nas publicações do utilizador a ser removido, no entanto, são sempre mantidos, uma vez que as publicações também.

O facto de ser necessária intervenção humana aqui, também faz com que por vezes passems mais do que as 24h que o sistema avisa que tens para cancelar a remoção, antes da conta ser removida — **e pedidos de cancelamento após essas 24h não são fiavelmente registados pelo sistema**.

Posto tudo isto, e voltando ao primeiro parágrafo: reassociámos as publicações anteriormente associadas ao teu perfil anterior ao teu perfil actual. A reputação que tinhas ganho com essas publicações deverá, salvo algumas excepções, ser reavida também. No entanto, os votos que tinhas anteriormente feito não são recuperáveis.

Portanto, termino com um lembrete para o futuro: **evitem pedir remoção de conta num capricho, ou para testar botões, ou seja o que for — há toda uma comunidade de utilizadores que pode ficar afectada com isso, como aconteceu aqui.** [Como o Maniero disse:](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6799/23291)

> Fez um estrago na reputação de muita gente

Answer (score 7):

Infelizmente não tem como, tudo é removido mesmo.

Fez um estrago na reputação de muita gente, mas não foi culpa sua.

Comment: Não dá para um CM dar um jeito nisso?

Comment: @VictorStafusa até onde eu sei é um problema técnico, os dados são apagados mesmo.